# generate unduplicated data and save in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using `AWS DynamoDB` and I generate a 6-digit number using `Math.random()` for saving to `DB`

and this number should be unique, it means I have to scan all data in `DB` before putting it.

this is my code for generating a unique 6-digit number with `for-loop`

```js
async function getUniqueKey(){
  let key = '';
  const arr = new Array(100).fill(0).map((el, index) => index+1);
  for(const i of arr){
    key = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1).toString().padStart(6,"0");
    const params = {
      TableName: "my_table",
      FilterExpression: "myUniqueKey= :myUniqueKey",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":myUniqueKey": key
      }
    }
    const res:any = await DYNAMO_DB.scan(params).promise();
    if(res.Items.length === 0){
      break;
    }
  }
  return key;
}
```

this code is working well,

but I just wonder is it the best solution in DynamoDB.

I am a newbie in DynamoDB so sometimes I feel I do something wrong way.

Comment: random doesn't mean unique....

Comment: I know, that's why I checked that is unique in DB with `for-loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be FAR more efficient to do a putItem or update with a [conditional expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites). With this, you write the item only if the partition key does not exist already. If it does exist, it errors and you try another number.

Scans are expensive, both in time and money. So they should usually only be done if you really have to.